# rows after a specific event in time FOR A KEY

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table like below,

[image]

and I am trying to get all rows after the first occurrence of a specific event for a key + the row that contains the event, like below for 'xn'  (column1),

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the [QUALIFY()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html) function? Works nicely here combined with [MIN()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/min.html) and windowing over your required keys.

Also if you'd like quicker answers sometimes supplying the cte's used to test and run your question might speed up answers.

[image]

Copy|Paste|Run

```
WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('9/1/2021 10:10','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') AS TIMESTAMP , 'A' KEY ,'XA' AS COLUMN_1
UNION
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('9/1/2021 10:11','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') AS TIMESTAMP , 'A' KEY,'XN' AS COLUMN_1
UNION
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('9/1/2021 10:12','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') AS TIMESTAMP , 'A' KEY,'XN' AS COLUMN_1
UNION
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('9/1/2021 10:13','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') AS TIMESTAMP , 'A' KEY,'XD' AS COLUMN_1
UNION
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('9/1/2021 10:14','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') AS TIMESTAMP , 'A' KEY,'XT' AS COLUMN_1
UNION
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('9/1/2021 10:15','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') AS TIMESTAMP , 'A' KEY,'XM' AS COLUMN_1
UNION
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('9/1/2021 10:16','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') AS TIMESTAMP , 'A' KEY,'XJ' AS COLUMN_1
UNION
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('9/1/2021 10:12','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') AS TIMESTAMP , 'B' KEY,'XR' AS COLUMN_1
UNION
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('9/1/2021 10:13','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') AS TIMESTAMP , 'B' KEY,'XU' AS COLUMN_1
UNION
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('9/1/2021 10:14','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') AS TIMESTAMP , 'B' KEY,'XN' AS COLUMN_1
UNION
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('9/1/2021 10:15','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') AS TIMESTAMP , 'B' KEY,'XI' AS COLUMN_1
UNION
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('9/1/2021 10:16','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') AS TIMESTAMP , 'B' KEY,'XH' AS COLUMN_1 )
SELECT 
*  
FROM 
CTE 
QUALIFY 
TIMESTAMP >= MIN(DECODE(COLUMN_1,'XN', TIMESTAMP ,NULL) ) OVER 
(PARTITION BY KEY ORDER BY  TIMESTAMP)
```